# Issues with sharing hp usb printer

Tags: drivers, usb, printing, samba, hp

I have an HP LaserJet Pro M1136 printer which is installed in a win 7 32 bit system through usb and I'm trying to share it to a system with ubuntu 14.04 64 bit installed.  At first I tried by going to the printer option in system settings and then adding the printer through the "Windows printer via samba option" I also installed hplip latest version through terminal and after adding the printer I tried printing a test page but it doesn't works and under the Ink/Toner levels it says "hplip plugin required".  The printer works fine when its connected to an ubuntu machine through usb but I can't get it to work through sharing it from a windows machine.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu

this is the ubuntu guide; it has always seemed comprehensive

the final section is troubleshooting; no 2 is about subnets

```
2. Networking issues.
```

Be careful about using different network masks/subnets on your network where you would like to share the printer.

If the subnets differs, e.g. on the print server there would be a /24 (255.255.255.0) netwok mask configured, and e.g. on the clients there would be a /16 (255.255.0.0) network mask - perhaps provided by the DHCP server, this might cause a problem that clients won't be able to detect any shared printer on the server, even if other communications between print server and clients would be possible (e.g. ICMP, ssh) and successful.

If such situation happens, you have to unify the network masks/subnets on all of your stations, e.g. use /24 (255.255.255.

let us know if this is any help

Answer (score 0):

Just to update what finally happened is that I connected the printer through usb to ubuntu system and then shared it from ubuntu to and then connected to the shared printer through a windows 7 syetem.